# I have made a guess the number game but every time i run it and type a number this it crashes

Tags: python

this is my code:

```
#This is a guess the number game
import random

print('Hello what is your name')
name = input()
secretNumber = random.randint(1, 20)
print('Well ' + name + ' I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20. You have 6 guesses')

#Ask the player to guess 6 times.
for guessTaken in range(1, 7):

    try:
        print('Take a guess')
        guess = int(input())
    except ValueError:
            print('That is not a number')

    guess = int(input())
    guess = str(input())
    if guess < secretNumber:
        print('Your guess is to low.')
    elif guess > secretNumber:
        print('Your gues s is to high.')
    else:
        break # This condition is the correct guess!

if guess == secretNumber:
    print('Good job ' + name + '. You guessed my number!')
    print('It was ' + str(secretNumber))
    print('and you guessed it in ' + str(guessTaken) + ' guesses')
else:
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + str(secretNumber))
```

when ever i run it and type a number this comes up: guess = int(input())
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: What do you think   `guess = str(input())` right after `guess = int(input())` is going to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#This is a guess the number game
import random


name = input('Hello what is your name: ')
secretNumber = random.randint(1, 20)
print('Well, ' + name + ' I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20. You have 6 guesses')

#Ask the player to guess 6 times.
for guessTaken in range(1, 7):

    try:
        guess = int(input('Take a guess: '))
    except ValueError:
            print('That is not a number')

    if guess < secretNumber:
        print('Your guess is to low.')
    elif guess > secretNumber:
        print('Your guess is to high.')
    else:
        break # This condition is the correct guess!

if guess == secretNumber:
    print('Good job ' + name + '. You guessed my number!')
    print('It was ' + str(secretNumber))
    print('and you guessed it in ' + str(guessTaken) + ' guesses')
else:
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + str(secretNumber))
```

You didn't need:

```
    guess = int(input())
    guess = str(input())
```

Comment: Your code will crash if you get an error, where will guess be defined?, input also takes an argument so you don't need to print

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want

```
guess = int(input())
guess = str(input())
```

in your loop. Try getting rid of those (you only need to take user input once during that loop, not three times). Keep the `guess = int(input())` inside of the `try` block, though.